# How can I get a continuous stream of samples from the JavaScript AudioAPI

Tags: web-audio-api

I'd like to get a continuous stream of samples in JavaScript from the audio API.  The only way I've found to get samples is through the MediaRecorder object in the JavaScript Audio API.

I set up my recorder like this:

```
var options = {
  mimeType: "audio/webm;codec=raw",
}
this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
  this.decodeChunk(e.data);
}.bind(this);
this.mediaRecorder.start(/*timeslice=*/ 100 /*ms*/);
```

This gives me a callback 10 times a second with new data.  All good so far.

The data is encoded, so I use audioCtx.decodeAudioData to process it:

```
let fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onloadend = () => {
  let encodedData = fileReader.result;
  // console.log("Encoded length: " + encodedData.byteLength);
  this.audioCtx.decodeAudioData(encodedData,
    (decodedSamples) => {
      let newSamples = decodedSamples.getChannelData(0)
        .slice(this.firstChunkSize, decodedSamples.length);
      // The callback which handles the decodedSamples goes here.  All good.
      if (this.firstChunkSize == 0) {
        this.firstChunkSize = decodedSamples.length;
      }
    });
};
```

This all works fine too.

Setting up the data for the file reader is where it gets strange:

```
let blob;
if (!this.firstChunk) {
  this.firstChunk = chunk;
  blob = new Blob([chunk], { 'type': chunk.type });
} else {
  blob = new Blob([this.firstChunk, chunk], { 'type': chunk.type });
}
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

The first chunk works just fine, but the second and later chunks fail to decode unless I combine them with the first chunk.  I'm guessing what is happening here is that the first chunk has a header that is required to decode the data.  I remove the samples decoded from the first chunk after decoding them a second time.  See `this.firstChunkSize` above.

This all executes without error, but the audio that I get back has a vibrato-like effect at 10Hz.  A few hypotheses:

1. I have some simple mistake in my "firstChunkSize" and "splice" logic
2. The first chunk has some header which is causing the remaining data to be interpreted in a strange way.
3. There is some strange interaction with some option when creating the audio source (noise cancellation?)

Comment: I've uncovered a hint: This assertion succeeds after creating the mediaRecorder, but fails in the ondataavailable callback: console.assert(this.mediaRecorder.mimeType == "audio/webm;codec=raw").  The codec seems to change to "opus", but I don't know why.  I'm using Chrome v86.

Comment: Same happens when I try to use audio/webm;codecs=pcm, which is a valid type per: MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm;codecs=pcm')

Answer (score 1):

You want `codecs=`, not `codec=`.

```
var options = {
  mimeType: "audio/webm;codecs=pcm",
}
```

Though `MediaRecorder.isSupported` will return true with `codec=` it is only because this parameter is being ignored.  For example:

```
MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/webm;codec=pcm")
true
MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/webm;codecs=pcm")
true
MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/webm;codecs=asdfasd")
false
MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/webm;codec=asdfasd")
true
```

The garbage codec name `asdfasd` is "supported" if you specify `codec` instead of `codecs`.